# Python, sqlalchemy compare the model and the table in the database

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, orm, alembic

Is it possible to compare a model and a table in a database and print out the difference between them?
For example different columns, different data types of columns.
I don't need migrations, just compare model and table.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.